# Is there a maximum amount of iterations PHP can loop?

Tags: php, loops

Given the right configuration, a very simple process and enough memory, does PHP have a ceiling on number of iterations in loops, or would it just continue to execute until you either exhausted the memory, hit the max execution time, or faulted in some other way?

If so, is it different for the various types of loops? while, do...while, for, foreach?

**For instance:**

```
<?php 
for ($i=0; $i<999999999999999999; $i++) {
  echo "$i<br/>";
};
```

I realize this is a little absurd, but it's mostly a curiosity of mine about PHP limitations.  I couldn't find anything in the docs or this specific question discussed here on SO.

I did run this script in a local development environment running PHP 7.1 built in server on a 3.1GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro with 16GB RAM, with a `max_execution_time` of zero.  After about 720,000 the browser itself would reach it's own limitations and freeze up.  I did run this same test via the CLI and while it took a really long time, it did execute and ran but I eventually manually stopped it.

Comment: You have several things involved - maximum buffer size (your echo), max int size (you can do `while(true)` which doesn't care about that)...

Comment: The limit is `999999999999999999` in your code, though a `while(true)` could iterate forever.

Comment: A loop doesn't use any memory; the limits you're running into are elsewhere in the web server/network/browser stack.

Comment: Cut the browser out of the equation. Run the script server side, does it end?

Comment: @chris85 running that now and it's chugging along nicely with no end in site, although I'm giving my fans a good workout.

Comment: I'm reminded of Raymond Chen's "If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong"... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070301-00/?p=27803

Comment: @Kevin Fee ha. nice jab.  and perhaps.  But more of a curiosity than anything as explained in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser would freeze since it won't get a response, unless it get's a `500` or any other error status/response. PHP, in theory, could run indefinitelly.

For example, I use something like this to handle some "jobs" in the background:

```
while(true) {
    // and I do some wonders here
    // if some conditions are met
}
```

When it comes to your browser, yes - it will freeze whilst awaiting the `200 OK` response code which will definitelly not arrive because of the web server `TimeOut` configuration, PHP's `max_execution_time` setting (and others) ... and many other factors, not mentioning the size of the data transmitted into your browser, which will do the actual "crash" of your browser in a case where you iterate and echo each number from `0` to `999999999999999999`.

Your `for` loop will reach it's destination of `999999999999999999` (probably not in your Browser, but definitelly in the terminal), unless something else stops it or breaks it (ie. CTRL+C, condition, `max_execution_time`, etc).

Comment: "Your for loop will reach it's destination of 999999999999999999 (probably not in your Browser, but definitelly in the terminal ....". The number in question is about 10^18; if the computer takes 1 nanosecond (e.g. 1 cycle per increment running on a 1 GHz core) per increment, thta's already 10^9 seconds -- roughly 30 years.

Comment: Actually, the browser will freeze since the server will send data to it, but there won't be an ending '200 OK' response from the server - probably never. I don't know what I've said wrong nor how I'm confused? Please elaborate. (english is not my primary)

Comment: To comment on what @Kevin said, i just did a quick calculation for a modern 8-core 5GHz CPU, and could make a program that roughly iterated through a loop of this size in ~300 days. Still completely unusable for most situations.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr

PHP will gladly loop forever assuming it has enough resources and that the process isn't terminated by the operating system, Apache, user, etc...

---

You are confusing a browser issue with PHP. The browser cannot handle the rendering of so many `echo "$i<br/>";` so it crashes or freezes or whatever. It's also possible that PHP is running out of memory by placing so many `$i` into the output buffer before it sends it to the browser.

Try benchmarking the code properly and you will quickly get your answer:

```
// Let's set the start timer
$start = microtime(true);

// Add or remove 9's as you please
for($i=0; $i<999999999999999999; ++$i){}

// How many seconds did this take to complete?
echo (microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<br/>';

// What was the peak memory usage during this code execution?
echo memory_get_peak_usage(true).' bytes used';
```

Assuming Apache/PHP/your browser does not time out then you should see a result; if not then go command-line.

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't say i was confusing the browser with PHP. I understand that the browser reached it's own limitations before PHP would, that was just the first test I ran.

Comment: @RobertWade My mistake; the code sample led me to the wrong conclusion. In any case, I hope my example helps. Also, take note of the `++$i` versus `$i++` :)

Comment: so pre incrementing the index will prevent the output buffer limitations?

Comment: @RobertWade Nope, it's just micro-optimization which causes `$i` to increment faster. Not really noticeable in the real world but if you had an operation with millions of iterations then it reduces execution time by 30% or more depending on the PHP version.

Comment: Thank you. That is great to know.

Answer (score 5):

`999999999999999999` is beyond the maximum safe integer that can be represented. If you ask PHP how much is `9007199254740992 + 1` it will tell you it is `9007199254740992`. In other words:

```
<?php var_dump ((9007199254740992 + 1) === 9007199254740992);
```

Outputs `bool(true)`.

This is a limitation of floating point numbers. Because of it, your iteration variable `$i` will not reach `999999999999999999`. You have effectively created an infinite loop.

You may consider `9007199254740992` the limit. Of couse, this is because of the data type PHP uses for the variable ([double, a.k.a IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

---

You will have the same problem if you use an infinite loop and try to count the number of iterations. You may in theory use a library that can handle arbitrary large integers... But there is no reason why PHP would stop anyway, at least not before the hardware begin to fail.

**Trivia**: `999999999999999999 flop` executed at `100 gigaflop/second` would take `115 days 17 hours 46 minutes 40 seconds` to run.

---

**Errata**: On a 64 bits build of PHP the maximun safe integer that can be represented is `9223372036854775807`. In other words:

```
<?php var_dump ((9223372036854775808 + 1) === 9223372036854775808);
```

Outputs `bool(true)`

[Try online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b6b371a15e219920993672d388e86fb2438c865).

`9223372036854775808` is about one order of magnitud greater than `999999999999999999`, thus this loop is not infinite in a 64 bit build of PHP. This is not [quad precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format). Upon futher testing, turns out PHP is using a 64 bit integer up to `9223372036854775807` and then switch to double:

```
<?php
var_dump (serialize(9223372036854775807));
var_dump (serialize(9223372036854775808));
```

Outputs

```
string(22) "i:9223372036854775807;"
string(25) "d:9.2233720368547758E+18;"
```

[Try online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7eb26222b74d77684a5cb43fa0f6e58067bf72ee).

Meanwhile the 32 bits build will use a 32 bit intger up to `2147483647` and then use switch to double.

Comment: Is this specific to a certain PHP version or x86 versus x64? If not then testing `<?php var_dump ((9007199254740992 + 1) === 9007199254740992);` at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ must be pure sorcery.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus turns out you are right, I had not tested on a 64 bit build, added errata.

Comment: Very interesting answer! I was honestly not aware of this PHP intricacy before today so I'm glad that you've posted this answer :)

Comment: `999999999999999999` simply becomes a float (`var_dump(999999999999999999) -> float(1.0E+18)`), and I don't see why it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: @SalmanA Because when you get that high in numbers, you lose precision. Adding one may not be enough to tick up to the next integer because that next integer can't be represented in a float precisely. At this point, you can keep adding one as many times as you like and it's not going to change. Hence, infinite loop.

Comment: @SalmanA [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hdFG2GcNuA) uses Super Mario 64 to demonstrate this issue with floats, I found it very approachable.

Comment: @SalmanA [Why Computers are Bad at Algebra | Infinite Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQs_wx8eoQ8)